# Как сделать так, чтобы размеры изображения в окне менялись вместе с измененными размерами самого окна?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlayout, qlabel, resizeevent

Начал изучать *PyQt5* и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что фоновое изображение (`QLabel`, `QPixmap`) не меняется в зависимости от изменения размера окна (`QMainWindow`).

Пролистал множество сайтов и нашел функцию `resizeEvent()`, но не знаю как ее внедрить. 
Может быть есть альтернативные способы?

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore 
from  PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow 
from main_wK01 import K01


class Window(QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self):  
        super(Window, self).__init__() 
        self.setWindowTitle("ЭХЗ")  
        self.setGeometry(250, 120, 1270, 800)

        self.picture = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.picture.setGeometry(0, 0, 1270, 800)
        self.picture.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("logo.png"))
        self.picture.setScaledContents(True)

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.move(1120, 370)
        self.btn.setText("К-01")
        self.btn.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.K01)

        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn1.move(1120, 400)
        self.btn1.setText("К-03")
        self.btn1.setFixedWidth(150)

    def K01 (self):  
         self.bK01 = K01()
         self.bK01.show()


def application():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=="__main__":
    application()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Научитесь использовать [**менеджеры компоновки**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Например, класс [**QGridLayout**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html) размещает виджеты в сетке.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore 
from  PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow 

# ? from main_wK01 import K01


class Window(QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self):  
        super(Window, self).__init__() 
# !!! +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.centralWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 192, 225);")        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
# !!! +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
        self.setWindowTitle("ЭХЗ")  
# ?        self.setGeometry(250, 120, 1270, 800)

        self.picture = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
#        self.picture.setGeometry(0, 0, 1270, 800)
        self.picture.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Ok.png"))
        self.picture.setScaledContents(True)

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
#        self.btn.move(1120, 370)
        self.btn.setText("К-01")
        self.btn.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.K01)
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(192, 192, 225);")

        self.btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
#        self.btn1.move(1120, 400)
        self.btn1.setText("К-03")
        self.btn1.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(192, 192, 225);")

# !!! +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget) 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.picture, 0, 0, 4, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn1, 2, 1)
# !!! +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
    def K01 (self):  
# ?         self.bK01 = K01()
# ?         self.bK01.show()
        pass
         
         
def application():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=="__main__":
    application()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ksh что не так?

Comment: Большое спасибо, только что попробовал и все получилось. Это,видать, проблемы оказались с изображением и его размерностью.  Вы очень помогли. Спасибо.

Comment: @ksh пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour Да, непонятно, почему вы пишите, что проблема с изображением и его размерностью, проблема совсем в другом.